# Mapping InfluxDB series to a MongoDB collection containing all the metadata

Tags: database, mongodb, time-series, metadata, influxdb

I started working on project with InfluxDB recently and I need a help. Does anyone know how to map InfluxDB series to a MongoDB collection containing all the metadata?

Comment: Obviously, you write a small app/script that takes points from Influx, parses it, reshapes it into Mongo records & posts it into Mongo. Although, you didn't specify what problems you're bumped in. Could you, please?

Comment: I want to store time series in InfluxDB, but the metadata for each one to be stored in MongoDB. I'm actually working on creating a data hub where it can be possible to store, search and retrieve time series data by some attributes.

Comment: I know it is a pretty old post, but did you find a path/solution to your solution @I25M?